# cloud_tpc empty in OpenNI listener in RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I was stepping through the RGBDSLAM code, and I found that even though I have a Kinect connected to my PC, noCloudCallback() is called instead of kinectCallback() because the cloud_tpc string is always empty.

```
ParameterServer* params = ParameterServer::instance();
...
std::string cloud_tpc = params->get<std::string>("topic_points");
...
//All information from Kinect
if(!visua_tpc.empty() && !depth_tpc.empty() && !cloud_tpc.empty())
{   
    ...
    kinect_sync_->registerCallback(boost::bind(&OpenNIListener::kinectCallback, this, _1, _2, _3));
    ...
} 
//No cloud, but visual image and depth
else if(!visua_tpc.empty() && !depth_tpc.empty() && !cinfo_tpc.empty() && cloud_tpc.empty())
{   
    ...
    no_cloud_sync_->registerCallback(boost::bind(&OpenNIListener::noCloudCallback, this, _1, _2, _3));
    ...
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is the case and why I have to do to call the kinectCallback()?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54504/cloud_tpc-empty-in-openni-listener-in-rgbdslam/) by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the corresponding parameter in the launch file, e.g:

```
<param name="config/topic_points" value="/camera/depth_registered/points"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on 2013-02-07**:
Can you please specify which launch file? Do you mean the openni launch file? I am running RGBDSLAM like this
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-07**:
just running rgbdslam with rosrun will use the default parameters. You best use a launchfile e.g.  rgbdslam/launch/rgbdslam.launch and modify the parameters to your needs (add the line in my answer, if not already contained). then launch it as "roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch"